# Confusing notation in Wikipedia's quantum channel article

Tags: quantum-operation, terminology-and-notation

In the Wikipedia's [Quantum channel article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_channel), it is said that a purely quantum channel $\phi$ (it's not exactly the same phi calligraphy but it's close), in the Schrodinger picture, is a linear map between density matrices acting on two Hilbert spaces. Then properties of this mapping are given and we find the following notation :

$$I_n \otimes \Phi$$
 We find again this difference of notation in the Heisenberg picture paragraph. 
However I believe  $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the same and I don't understand the change of notation between the twos. Is there a difference justifying this change or is it a lack of coherence of the notation ?

Comment: I think it's just notational inconsistency. If you look at the page code, the symbols are generated in two different ways: in the text, someone has just inserted the greek letter symbol (presumably a unicode character) whereas in the equation, they've used LaTeX. They're clearly both supposed to be capital phi.

Comment: Thank you DaftWullie, it's good enough for me as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted if you put it in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's just notational inconsistency. If you look at the page code, the symbols are generated in two different ways: in the text, someone has just inserted the greek letter symbol (presumably a unicode character) whereas in the equation, they've used LaTeX. They're clearly both supposed to be capital phi.

Comment: thanks, I'm modifying the Wikipedia page to get consistent notation